# If a HRE nation rivalled to the Holy Roman Emperor, will they respond to wars of aggression against HRE nations from non-HRE nations?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm playing as Burgundy, trying to form the Netherlands. Utrecht has all the 4 provinces I need but is currently in the HRE. The current plan is to declare war with CB Conquest with Austria and France as allies; France is currently at war, so I'm waiting for the time being.

I'm afraid that an enlarged Brandenburg may call and join the war with a better military than me. However is is rivalled to the Palatinate, currently the Holy Roman Emperor. I'm uncertain that Brandenburg will answer the call of the Emperor while it is its rival.

Comment: This is pretty much unanswerable. You don't even say, which nation you play and what your current status is. Nor do say, who you want to attack, just provinces in the low countries. How is anybody supposed to assess your situation? If this is just about, whether you should attack an HRE member, the emperor has rivalled from outside the HRE, the answer is maybe. There is a chance, the emperor declines the defend the empire call, when you attack their rival, but it is by no means guaranteed.

Comment: As @Dulkan mentioned, we need more info but as a general rule the HRE emperor will answer the call even if the HRE member and the Emperor are rivaled.

Comment: @Dulkan I added more info, comment again if needed.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Palatinate is emperor and rivalled to Brandenburg, yes? Why should Brandenburg join the war then? The emperor cannot call random HRE nations into defend the empire, they can only call their allies. You'd only have to worry about Brandenburg, if they are allied to the emperor or your target. Why are you afraid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a non-HRE nation attacks a country whose capital is an HRE province, the emperor will be called into war. The emperor can then call their allies to war.

When you are the attacking nation, you can see if the emperor will decline or accept to be in this war, and for what reasons (relations to the battling nations, debt, war exhaustion plays into this)

So assuming you are attacking the rival of the emperor, the emperor is slightly less likely to join the war on the defending side. Keep in mind that this modifier is as far as I know less significant than the default attitude from being the emperor, meaning for the emperor to not do their job, they should need additional reasons (such as being massively in debt, being scared of the agressor)

The emperor defends (if he wants to) it's subjects, but other the subjects will not by default be called into a war, unless by another factor (such as an alliance)